# An equality with vectors

Tags: optimization, vectors, normed-spaces

Here is a problem with its solution.

Let $\mathbf{s}_{n\times1}$ is a vector with elements $s_{j}\in\left[-1,1\right]$
for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. I have the equality 
$$
\lambda\alpha\mathbf{s}=\mathbf{a}
$$
where $\lambda$ is an unknown parameter, $\alpha\in\left(0,1\right)$
is a fixed constant and $\mathbf{a}$ is an $n\times1$ vector. We
can show that the minimum value of $\lambda$ that satisfies this
equality for some $s_{j}\in\left[-1,1\right]$ is 
$$
\lambda_{min}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\left\Vert \mathbf{a}\right\Vert _{\infty}
$$
where $\left\Vert \mathbf{a}\right\Vert _{\infty}=\max_{j}\left|a_{j}\right|$.
I would like to extend this equality with a fixed vector $\mathbf{b}$ like this:
$$
\lambda(\alpha\mathbf{s}+\left(1-\alpha\right)\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{a}
$$
The problem is the same: What is the minimum value of $\lambda$ (if
exists) that satisfies this equality for some $s_{j}\in\left[-1,1\right]$?

I tried to use inequalities with absolute values but could not get a solution.

Comment: is $b$ fixed? do you mean 'for some s_j' (instead of 'for all')?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: did you appreciate my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be summarized as:
$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R},y \in [-\alpha,\alpha]^n} \{ x : xy + x(1-\alpha)b = a\}$$
Substitute $xy=z$:
$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R},z \in [-\alpha x,\alpha x ]^n} \{ x : z + x(1-\alpha)b = a\}$$
The dual problem is:
$$ \max_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n,w_1 \in \mathbb{R}_+^n,w_2 \in \mathbb{R}_+^n} \{ a^Tv :     (1-\alpha)b^Tv + \alpha e^T(w_1+w_2) = 1, \; e^T(v + w_1-w_2) = 0\}$$
I do not see an immediate solution to any of these problems, but the last two problems you can just feed to a linear optimization solver.